# Email-Id Pick through click event from email

Tags: php, yii

How to pick email-ID of the user from email, when user click on the given link in the email.

Comment: I think you need the link to have a GET parameter in which you store the id and on the script you check if the variable is set and do stuff, iy you want to know who did this add a unique hash of the user